# Assigning characters one-by-one to a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

I want an array of, say, 10 pointers that point to arrays of characters. For the sake of simplicity, let them all point to the same array of characters. Here is one way:

```
const int N = 10;
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
char *pArr[N] = {NULL};
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     pArr[i] = &arr[0];
```

Instead of calling `pArr[i] = &arr[0]`, **can I assign the characters one by one?** Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          pArr[i][j] = arr[j];
```

except this code segfaults. Does the right-hand side of the assignment have to be an address?

EDIT: I want to be able to delete `arr` but not lose the data in `pArr`. I guess I just need a 2-D array.

Comment: "I want an array of, say, 10 pointers that point to arrays of characters" sure? why not a `std::vector<std::string>` ? It achieves the same (and more) with much less headaces

Comment: Why use the c-pointer style, if you use C++?

Comment: You do `pArr[i][j]`, but `p[i]` is NULL.

Comment: What do you try to acess here `pArr[i][j]`?

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? Why do you think you need an array of pointers to c-arrays of `char`?

Comment: Following your edit: 2D arrays won't really help - you need to copy *actual data*! Otherwise, if you assign the address of some data to a pointer, then 'delete' that data, the pointer will be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code (causing the segmentation fault) is this line:

```cpp
pArr[i][j] = arr[j];
```

Now, you are correct in assuming that, as `pArr` is an array of pointers, you can use each of its elements (that is `parr[i]`) as an 'array'; however, you can *only* do this *after* you have assigned a value to that element (i.e. after the `parr[i]` element in question has been given a valid address).

So, after the execution of your **first** code block, each `pArr[i]` value will point to the given array, so you can use `pArr[i][j]` to access individual elements of that array.

However, in your second block, the attempt to assign a value to `pArr[i][j]` causes the compiler to (attempt to) dereference the address corresponding to each `pArr[i]` with the `j` index added to it. But the `pArr[i]` elements have not yet been assigned values, so this attempt fails.

I'm not *entirely* sure what you are trying to achieve but, if you want each element of `pArr` to point to the 'corresponding' character element of `arr`, then you can use code like this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     pArr[i] = &arr[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

> But instead of calling pArr[i] = &arr[0], can I assign the characters one by one? Something like:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
> {
>      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
>      {
>           pArr[i][j] = arr[j];
>      }
> }
> ```

If `pArr[i]` is null, then `pArr[i][j] = arr[j]` indirects through the null pointer and behaviour of the program is undefined.

Rather than "instead", the shown snippet is perfectly valid **after** you've initialised the pointers to point to (elements of) array(s) of sufficient size. Given the initialisation in the example, all pointers point to the same element of same  array. Repeating the same modification on the same array would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you try to do (Example with **THREE** differents table) :

```
const int N = 10;

char arr1[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
char arr2[] = {'d', 'e', 'f','g', '\0'};
char arr3[] = {'h', 'i', '\0'};
char* pArr[N] ;

pArr[0] = (char*) calloc ( 1, sizeof(arr1));
pArr[1] = (char*) calloc ( 1, sizeof(arr2));
pArr[2] = (char*) calloc ( 1, sizeof(arr3));


for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr1); i++)
    pArr[0][i] = arr1[i];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr2); i++)
    pArr[1][i] = arr2[i];

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr3); i++)
    pArr[2][i] = arr3[i];
```

Note that you need to allocate memory for your "pArr" otherwise, you will have a **segmentation fault**